# Why does VMware VM believe its disk usage is larger than it is?

Tags: vmware-workstation, disk-space

In VMware Workstation 10 I can go to the VM menu, Manage, "Clean Up Disks..." and then magically, it will reclaim a ton of space.

What I don't understand is how the resulting folder for my VM is now only 80.1 GB. If I boot Windows in the VM and view the disk usage, it's about 91 GB. **How is this possible?**

Comment: What do you mean by "view the disk usage"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Probably Windows Explorer, Properties of volume (the pie chart)

Comment: @DanielBeck Correct. The same method I'm using the view the size of the folder of the VM on the host. Not that that's significant.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something made a file within the filesystem that actually consists of lots of zeros? If this were the case then the inner filesystem's usage may be bigger than that of the outer VMDK containing it because VMware may detect runs of zeros and essentially store them in a more efficient manner within the file representing the VMDK. Not all data is equal...

Answer (score 0):

[First result from Google](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-421A1073-BF16-4BC7-AA76-46B954CA438D.html)

> When you delete files from your virtual machine, the disk space occupied by those files is not immediately returned to your host system. If a virtual disk has such empty space, you can use the Clean up disks command to return that space to the hard drive on a Microsoft Windows host.
>
> The Clean up disks command is similar to the Compact command in the Workstation virtual machine settings and the shrink command provided by VMware Tools. The Clean up disks command has these advantages:
>
> You can use the Clean up disks command with virtual machines that have snapshots or are linked clones or parents of a linked clone.
>
> The Clean up disks command reclaims more disk space than the Compact command.
>   The Clean up disks command reclaims disk space from the current state of the virtual machine, from any powered-off snapshots, and from any powered-on snapshots where the guest operating system is Windows XP or later and you have installed a version of VMware Tools that is compatible with Workstation 8 or later.
>
> Unlike the Defragment command and the shrink command provided by VMware Tools, the Clean up disks command does not require any extra disk space on the host. The Clean up disks command operates directly on the virtual disk (.vmdk) files.

Comment: Also in the future please review the tips on [asking questions](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and have researched the question before asking.  This is most likely why someone down voted this question.

Comment: Pretty sure you missed the point here. The question is regarding how the resulting VM files (including, the one representing the entire disk) is **smaller** than what the VM believes it is.

Comment: Thin provisioning

Comment: Then provisioning is about having a 120GB "disk" but if only 80GB is used then it only takes up 80GB of space. The situation here is 91GB of data is taking 80.1 GB of space.

Comment: Just because it shows up as 80GB inside the VM doesn't mean it's a direct correlation to the .vmdk disk size.  The way Thin provisioning works is that it allocates based on the amount of space used or touched by the operating system.  If your VM's virtual memory ballooned for some reason, or if you made a large file copy that used temp caches on the hard drive, this could have ballooned the .vmdk to above the 80 that Windows reports being used.

Comment: Once the .vmdk has grown it doesn't shrink so if the size ever ballooned to 91GB then that's where it will stay until more space is requested by the operating system.

Comment: 91 INSIDE the VM. 80.1 on the host. The VM says it's larger than it is.

Comment: Sorry, misread that.  Not sure why that would right off hand.  Without knowing more about your setup and virtual environment it's hard to say.  Was this deployed from a template or a standalone VM?  Do you have other machines or hard drives on that machine?  What kind of storage device are you using?  Does the VM have any snapshots?<<--- that one is really important.  Get me some more details and I might can help.  Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: No problem. I agree, only compression makes sense, but it's surprising I find zero resources that say it uses compression. Standalone VM, not a linked-clone. I do have other machines on this host. Storage device of the host? Dual SSDs/Software RAID-0/NTFS. VM is thin-provisioned single-file VMDK. Snapshots? Maybe, but now I can't check because this was a year ago.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind that may explain this is that a snapshot had taken place at a point when the hard drive was 80GB and there would have been another file with the changed blocks since the snapshot was taken that would contain the other data.  That's the most plausible answer.  Sorry this is late.